# where can I download kony middleware file?

Tags: temenos-quantum

I would like to connect kony to Java, and it is said to use an interface called 'JavaService'. But I can't find it from anywhere. Is there anyone who can help me out?

- update

Below is my code for test.

```
public class HelloWorld implements JavaService2 {


@Override
public Object invoke(String methodId, Object[] maps, DataControllerRequest req,
  DataControllerResponse res) throws Exception {

  return sendMessage();
}// invoke

public Result sendMessage() {
  Result result = new Result();

  result.addParam(new Param("msg", "Hello Kony!"));
  System.out.println("sendMessage - Hello World!");

  return result;
}// sendMessage

}// class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement JavaService interface.
[see how to implement java service](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/konyfabric/kony_fabric_user_guide/Default.htm#Services.htm#Writing%3FTocPath%3DFeatures%7CIntegration%7CHow%2520to%2520Configure%2520a%2520Java%2520Adapter%7C_____2)

The dependency files are present inside middleware-system.jar
This jar is present inside your middleware.war file

Please let me know if you have more question
Thanks

Comment: Yes both are fine. By both I mean middleware.war and services.war.   Ultimately you need middleware-system.jar

Comment: I found the service.war file which was able to find JavaService interface.
I have few questions.
1. How can we test if it works?
2. I implemented the JavaService2 interface and made .jar file to upload it. But when I try to publish kony fabric, it says it is not the .jar file which is required for my environment I've chosen. (if needed, I will update the exact error message later)

Would you be nice to answer about it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have written for java service ? And how did you generate the jar file?   You can test it from mobile fabric console once you successfully upload the jar file. At this point I would say, read mobile fabric documentation that explains how to write and publish java service.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it with the link in your answer.
I updated my question with my Java code. Would you be nice to check if I have done something wrong?

Comment: This code is absolutely fine as far as I know. If you are using eclipse then just click on file -> export as jar, and make sure you have included the relevant files. Code is correct.

Comment: To be more detailed, to export jar, file -> export, "Jar file" not "executable jar", click next and choose only the java file and nothing else and then click on finish

Comment: I found out that it was my version problem.  Thank you for help!